# How to detect performance issues within native Android app

Tags: performance, load-testing

What tools or techniques can be used to performance/load test a native Android application?

Are there any that can detect the root cause of performance issues and suggest a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's acquired and cannot using"? Do you mean it's not free?

Comment: Since It was acquired by Facebook. No support for new user anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Good free solutions are:

- [**AT&T Application Resource Optimizer**](http://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer)
- [**Relic Mobile**](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring)

---

Also you can try the following commercial ones:

- [Soasta's solution](http://www.soasta.com/testing-solutions/mobile-performance-testing/)
- [Neotys' solution](http://www.neotys.com/introduction/mobile-load-testing.html)